# does anything like "void foo(int *const *p) "really exist?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() 
{ 
int i = 11; 
int *p = &i; 
foo(&p); 
printf("%d ", *p);
} 
void foo(int *const *p) 
{ int j = 10;
*p = &j;
printf("%d ", **p);
}
```

//it showed compile time error. Can anyone please explain

Comment: Of course there is an error and it is unrelated to `foo` but your `#include` line at the very least.

Comment: *"//it showed compile time error."* What error? Compilers give non-trivial diagnostic output, debugging is easier when you read it.

Comment: You're actually lucky that your code doesn't build, because you would otherwise dereference an invalid pointer and have *undefined behavior*. See [Can a local variable's memory be accessed outside its scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope) for details.

Comment: Is your question as in the title, or rather about why the code does not compile?  They appear to be two different and unrelated questions.  The argument type `int *const *` _pointer-to-const-pointer-to-int_ takes some thinking about, but is valid.

Comment: Initially " int *const * " seemed to be the reason of error. I want to know, why the code didn't compile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> int *const *p
> ```

`p` is a pointer to a **constant** pointer to `int`.

You can change `p` itself;
You cannot change `*p`;
You can change `**p`.

```
void foo(int *const *p) 
{ int j = 10;
*p = &j; // nope
printf("%d ", **p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you defined the method after calling it, so you should place it before `main()`